# Can Session_End fire on window close? (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, session, global-asax

I am putting an "online" counter on a website, and I have run into these two contradicting sources.

This one (I am using this example code):

http://aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/How-to-show-number-of-online-users-visitors-for-ASP-NET-website.aspx

...says that:

> Also when user closes his browser or does not click on any links in
>   our website, session expires,  and our "OnlineUsers" global variable
>   is decreased.

However, this one:

http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t383710-session-end-guarantee.html

...says that:

> Closing the browser window, or browsing to another site will NOT cause
>   Session_End to fire, at least, not straightaway - the server has
>   absolutely  no way of knowing what happens on the client machine until
>   it gets another  HttpRequest from it. In this instance, Session_End
>   will fire when the  session times out naturally.

I have tested and it seems that Session_End DOES NOT fire.

I basically want you guys to confirm or comment on this.

**Is it possible to update the online counter on browser-close?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second is true

> Closing the browser window, or browsing to another site will NOT cause
>   Session_End to fire, at least, not straightaway - the server has
>   absolutely no way of knowing what happens on the client machine until
>   it gets another HttpRequest from it. In this instance, Session_End
>   will fire when the session times out naturally.

Session time out is 20 minutes by default. You can confirm this by not doing any activity on your website for 20 min.

Answer (score 3):

Your two links are not contradictory.  The first link is poorly worded, but it basically says what the second link says.  It would be easier to understand if it were written like this:

> Also when user closes his browser or does not click on any links in our website (after a period of time) the session will expire, and our "OnlineUsers" global variable is decreased.

Also note that Session_End may not always fire, especially if the session is killed or bounced (for example, if you update the web.config, the worker process recycles, or in some cases an uncaught exception occurs).

Answer (score 2):

As is pointed out later in the first link posted the Session_End event fires after the session timeout expires. If the user who is associated with a session sends no requests to the server before the session timeout value expires the session_end event will be fired and the session will be removed from memory.

MSDN for asp.net session state: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Comment: You say that there are ways to handle browser close events. I have earlier played around with `onunload` or `onbeforeunload`, but they only work in IE, as far as I have discovered...

Comment: you would need to setup something like longpolling (lookup signalR or comet) in order to determine when a browser disconnects. By default you should expect all pages once rendered to be completely disconnected. I have removed the sentence you refer to so as to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Jeeper these events work with all browser; you can confirm this on stackoverflow question or answer page. However I don't recommend you to expire user session by these events.

Comment: @WaqasRaja : Yeah, since it also unloads when you stay on the site, it's not exactly brilliant ;)

Comment: if you are referring to the asp.net unload event that is part of the page's life-cycle: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.unload.aspx. It is useful when you are creating custom controls and want to run some cleanup code. It can also be useful if you use a unit of work, you can initialize it on page_init and dispose of it on page_unload.